# Is it possible to increase price of an App?

Tags: ios-appstore

Is there any way to increase the price of an app being sold on the App Store? (Where one could increase the price as necessary).

Where I could read more about App selling strategies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set and change your price at any time. You can set price changes immediately, or scheduled ahead of time.

You can choose which price from a range of tiers provided by Apple.
eg. 99c, 1.99, 4.99, etc.

You can't yourself choose 49c or $2.68, or any arbitrary value.

See:

[Changing Product Pricing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH33-SW5)

[Scheduling Price Tier Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html)

[Pricing Tier Matrix](http://forecomm.mptw.fr/templates/PriceMatrix.html)